# Would a question about OpenGrok be on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked a question several months ago on SuperUser: [OpenGrok home page not refreshing when index updated](https://superuser.com/questions/698038/opengrok-home-page-not-refreshing-when-index-updated). It received very few views, despite a bounty being placed on the question. I'm unable to place another bounty without bring my reputation below "pleasant" levels.

The lack of responses made me wonder if OpenGrok questions are not well-suited to SuperUser. Would this be on-topic on Stack Overflow? It's certainly a program used (exclusively) by programmers, however there is a web-server configuration theme that leads me to question its appropriateness.

We have an [opengrok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengrok) tag and 38 questions related to it, but that doesn't mean they *should* be on this site. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No-one responded to this. So I've decided to go ahead and delete my original post on SuperUser and re-post onto Stack Overflow: [OpenGrok home page not refreshing when index updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076043/opengrok-home-page-not-refreshing-when-index-updated).

I guess the community will tell me whether that's on-topic.